# DefaultSubscriptionRegistry not adapt high concurrency and abnormal situation

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I developed a chat system using spring websocket and stomp. Recently found that, sometime many threads(over 400) was blocked at `DefaultSubscriptionRegistry$DestinationCache$1`:

```
"http-nio-8686-exec-41" #3822 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f26bc021000 nid=0x8c7a waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f2837af7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry$DestinationCache.getSubscriptions(DefaultSubscriptionRegistry.java:269)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000004c6969f98> (a org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry$DestinationCache$1)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry.findSubscriptionsInternal(DefaultSubscriptionRegistry.java:184)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractSubscriptionRegistry.findSubscriptions(AbstractSubscriptionRegistry.java:116)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.sendMessageToSubscribers(SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.java:328)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.java:260)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.java:238)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel.sendInternal(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:91)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:117)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.sendInternal(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:159)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:47)
```

I think `DestinationCache.getSubscriptions` will block when destination not found in `this.accessCache` by using `synchronized (this.updateCache)`.

Some situations will cause many threads blocked on this function.

One is pattern destination, which is not in accessCache.

Another situation is too many users and destinations, but `cacheLimit=1024` by default, so some will be remove from cache.

Another situation is network is bad or some other things, which made many or all websockets disconnect immediately, but messages comes and send by using `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend`, then threads will be blocked at `DestinationCache.getSubscriptions` because destinations not found.

I want to know whether there is a better way to avoid block?

Answer (score 1):

Today I found the same problem. It seems that increasing `cacheLimit` is good approach.

> One is pattern destination

Users can subscribe to destination by pattern, but when you send a message to a destination, the name of destination is known. 
I.e. `getSubscriptions(...)` accepts `destination` parameter which is not a pattern.

So, again, increasing `cacheLimit` should be enough to solve thread blocking.

Unfortunately it's impossible in spring WS XML configuration to specify `cacheLimit` for `simple-broker`. One can add the following to XML to bypass it:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler#0" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setCacheLimit" />
    <property name="arguments" value="8096"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ant matcher cause very poor performance in `synchronized` block.

You should implement a custom `subscriptionRegistry` like `DefaultSubscriptionRegistry` without using Ant Matcher.